# Multiple left joins show distinct result with last date

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to build a discussion board. Therefore I have 3 tables: t_posts, t_boards, t_board_categories. Posts contain Threads (where post_post_id IS NULL) and replies to threads (where post_post_id IS NOT NULL), so it is self-referring. Now I want to show the last 5 posts (Threads and/or Replies) in all boards of all categories. The sql currently looks like this:

```
SELECT p.post_id, 
       p.post_board_id, 
       p.post_user_id, 
       p2.post_title, 
       bc.bc_name, 
       Max(p.post_date) post_date 
FROM   t_posts p 
       LEFT JOIN t_posts p2 
              ON ( p2.post_post_id IS NULL 
                   AND ( p2.post_id = p.post_id 
                          OR p.post_post_id = p2.post_id ) ) 
       LEFT JOIN t_boards b 
              ON b.board_id = p.post_board_id 
       LEFT JOIN t_board_categories bc 
              ON bc.bc_id = b.board_bc_id 
WHERE  p.post_system_id = '1' 
       AND p.post_deleted = 0 
       AND bc.bc_deleted = 0 
       AND b.board_deleted = 0 
GROUP  BY p.post_id, 
          p2.post_id 
ORDER  BY p2.post_date DESC 
LIMIT  5
```

The result is almost what I want, except of, that multiple replies in one thread will lead to showing only that one thread. What I want is 5 different threads to be shown with the most recent answers, not only one thread 5 times.

I join t_posts p2 for showing the original thread title.

I also tried adding DISTINCT p2.post_id to the SELECT, but it does not change anything.

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `t_board_categories` (
 `bc_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `bc_name` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
 `bc_prio` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `bc_system_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `bc_deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`bc_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

CREATE TABLE `t_boards` (
 `board_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `board_bc_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `board_name` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `board_subtitle` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
 `board_prio` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `board_system_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `board_deleted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`board_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

CREATE TABLE `t_posts` (
 `post_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `post_user_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `post_title` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `post_text` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `post_post_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `post_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `post_board_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `post_system_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `post_deleted` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=205 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

INSERT INTO `t_board_categories` (`bc_id`, `bc_name`, `bc_prio`, `bc_system_id`, `bc_deleted`) VALUES (1, 'Test-Category', '1', '1', '0');

INSERT INTO `t_boards` (`board_id`, `board_bc_id`, `board_name`, `board_subtitle`, `board_prio`, `board_system_id`, `board_deleted`) VALUES (1, '1', 'Test-Board', 'Board Subtitle', '1', '1', '0');

INSERT INTO `t_posts` (`post_id`, `post_user_id`, `post_title`, `post_text`, `post_post_id`, `post_date`, `post_board_id`, `post_system_id`, `post_deleted`) VALUES
(1, 14, 'Thread 1', 'Test1', NULL, '2019-05-22 00:18:25', 1, 1, 0),
(2, 14, 'Thread 2', 'Test2', NULL, '2019-05-22 00:18:44', 1, 1, 0),
(3, 14, 'Thread 3', 'Test 3', NULL, '2019-05-22 00:18:51', 1, 1, 0),
(4, 19, 'Thread 4', 'Test 4', NULL, '2019-05-22 00:19:02', 1, 1, 0),
(5, 19, 'Thread 5', 'Test 5', NULL, '2019-05-22 00:19:07', 1, 1, 0),
(6, 19, 'Thread 6', 'Test 6', NULL, '2019-05-22 00:19:15', 1, 1, 0),
(7, 14, 'Reply', 'A', 5, '2019-05-22 00:19:46', 1, 1, 0),
(8, 14, 'Reply', 'B', 5, '2019-05-22 00:19:47', 1, 1, 0),
(9, 14, 'Reply', 'C', 5, '2019-05-22 00:19:49', 1, 1, 0);
```

Expected Result: One row for thread 1-5 with user-id and date of last reply (userid:14, date: 2019-05-22 00:19:49 for Thread 5, for Thread 1-4 last date is thread-date, userid is thread author userid)

I worked on this the whole evening, would be great to get some help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You have columns in the list of columns, that are neither an argument to an aggregation function nor in the `GROUP BY`. That can produce strange results and isn't even allowed in most DBMS or MySQL with a stricter configuration.

Comment: [Edit] your question and include the schema (as `CREATE TABLE` statements), sample data (as `INSERT INTO` statements) and the desired result with that sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample data suggests, that post levels cannot span more than two levels (`post_post_id` cannot be an ID of a post where `post_post_id` isn't null). Assuming that, you can try to use correlated subqueries getting the sub posts and the post for a post, order them by their date descending and use `LIMIT` to pick the top one. Also sort the main query by the date of the last sub post descending and use `LIMIT` to get the top 5. Something along the lines of:

```
SELECT bc1.bc_id,
       bc1.bc_name,
       b1.board_id,
       b1.board_name,
       p1.post_id,
       p1.post_title,
       (SELECT p2.post_title
               FROM t_posts p2
               WHERE p1.post_id IN (p2.post_id,
                                    p2.post_post_id) 
               ORDER BY p2.post_date DESC
               LIMIT 1) last_post_title,
       (SELECT p2.post_user_id
               FROM t_posts p2
               WHERE p1.post_id IN (p2.post_id,
                                    p2.post_post_id)
               ORDER BY p2.post_date DESC
               LIMIT 1) last_post_user_id,
       (SELECT p2.post_date
               FROM t_posts p2
               WHERE p1.post_id IN (p2.post_id,
                                    p2.post_post_id) 
               ORDER BY p2.post_date DESC
               LIMIT 1) last_post_date
       FROM t_posts p1
            INNER JOIN t_boards b1
                       ON b1.board_id = p1.post_board_id
            INNER JOIN t_board_categories bc1
                       ON bc1.bc_id = b1.board_bc_id
       WHERE p1.post_post_id IS NULL
       ORDER BY last_post_date DESC
       LIMIT 5;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=abfc2eecd86ba1925432d71023a282a8)

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much